# can't run ipython on cmd

Tags: python, ipython

I successfully installed ipython via pip. I wanted then to use it by launching it through windows 10 command prompt but am getting the following error

```
'ipython' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file.
```

I have gone through many questions on stackoverflow but cannot get a relevant solution.
I tried  `pip install ipython` to confirm the ipython is installed and following on the instruction on my tutorial, i typed `ipython` on cmd to launch the program and it has never worked. This is slowing down my learning, please help!

Comment: What is the result of command `pip install python` and which python version you are using?

Comment: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python.  python version  3.7.7

Comment: can you try `pip3 install ipython`?

Comment: I am getting installation requirements satisfied but `ipython` gives the same results

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Search in your machine the ipython application (directory in which it is installled) and the add the path to PATH environment variables.
For example in my case location was `C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts`
Add this path to PATH environment variable ([see here](https://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/tasks/fot-addpath.html)) and your problem is solved.

Comment: I do not know what you wanted to point to with your link, but following [the steps given here](https://www.makeuseof.com/python-windows-path/) to update PATH environment variables works well (with minor adjustments for Windows 11)

Answer (score 23):

Found the solution: run `python -m IPython` (case sensitive).

To find that out, I ran `pip show ipython` and it showed me some info, including the path of the module (for me: `c:\users\mathieures\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages`). In there, a folder named IPython!

Comment: This answer should be much easier to find.  This is clearly a problem with the current Windows installer for IP - especially since it is installed with the capitals for IP.  The average pip user would have guessed it was a module, but after installing lower case, it shouldn't have required the case sensitivity.  Pick one or the other, installers!

Comment: Mathieures, you're a gentleman and a scholar! Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

for first uninstall ipython `python -m pip uninstall ipython` then install ipython with code `python -m pip install ipython` when finished type ipython to run.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and what i simply did is uninstall it using `pip uninstall ipython` and then reinstall it using `pip install ipython` like the same as what Ali vatankhah did but without adding `python -m` in the command.

Answer (score 0):

just do this:
python -m IPython (be aware, case sensitive).

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.